# Problemas con CheckBoxFor y ListBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Necesito renderizar en mi vista una serie de campos tipo `checkbox` (9 en total) en donde si uno de ellos (el numero 8) al momento de hacer clic en el debería aparecer un campo tipo `select`, esto ultimo ya lo tengo desarrollado con `jquery` el tema de la animación para mostrar y ocultar el `div`. El problema que tengo esta en renderizar los `inputs` en la `view` con `razor`, hacer el modelo y manejar los datos en el controlador. Todos son datos estáticos.

Probé haciendo lo siguiente:

Model

*Este seria para los campos de tipo `checkbox`*

```
public class MiModeloCheckbox
{
    public MiModeloCheckbox()
    {
        this.Checkbox = new List<Checkbox>();
    }

    public List<Checkbox> Checkbox { get; set; }

    public class Checkbox
    {
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*Este seria para el campo de tipo `select`

```
public class MiModeloSelect
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Autos { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedAutos { get; set; }
}
```

*Finalmente cree un nuevo modelo para unir los dos anteriores y poder enviarlos a la vista desde mi `controller`.

```
public class Input
{
    public MiModeloCheckbox MiModeloCheckbox { get; set; }
    public MiModeloSelect MiModeloSelect { get; set; }
}
```

En mi `controller` tengo lo siguiente

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        // Logic

        Input input = new Input();
        input.MiModeloSelect.Autos = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "AUTO 1" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "AUTO 2" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "AUTO 3" }
        };

        return View(input);
    }
```

Pero en esta linea `input.MiModeloSelect.Autos` me da una excepción justo en `Autos` que dice lo siguiente:

> input.MiModeloSelect.Autos = 'input.MiModeloSelect.Autos' inició una excepción de tipo 'System.NullReferenceException'

En mi vista ocupo lo siguiente:

```
@model MiProyecto.Models.Input

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.MiModeloSelect.SelectedAutos, Model.MiModeloSelect.Autos)
```

No se como poder resolver este problema, ¿alguien que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Tu respuesta que habías dejado no la alcance a terminar de leer, ¿podrías volver a publicarla? para ver el ejemplo que colocaste, enseguida leeré el link que me dejaste.

Comment: ok, la he recuperado aunque no debería haberla respondido probablemente. Ya que está hecha, mira a ver si te sirve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces `Input input = new Input();` creas una instancia de `Input`, pero las variables internas de la clase permanecen a `null` si no las inicializas. Tienes un par de opciones:

1. Inicializarlo en el constructor de la clase:

   ```
   public class Input
   {
       public MiModeloCheckbox MiModeloCheckbox { get; set; }
       public MiModeloSelect MiModeloSelect { get; set; }

       public Input()
       {
             this.MiModeloCheckbox = new MiModeloCheckbox();
             this.MiModeloSelect = new MiModeloSelect();  
       }
   }
   ```
2. Inicializarlo al crear la instancia de la clase manualmente:

   ```
   Input input = new Input();
   input.MiModeloCheckbox = new MiModeloCheckbox();
   input.MiModeloSelect = new MiModeloSelect();
   ```

Un par de consideraciones adicionales:

1. Es muy mala práctica llamar a una propiedad igual que su clase, lleva a equívocos y hace más difícil leer el código.
2. Este problema te ocurrirá "recursivamente". Quiero decir que al hacer por ejemplo `input.MiModeloSelect = new MiModeloSelect();`, creas una instancia de `MiModeloSelect`, pero tanto `Autos` como `SelectedAutos` serán `null`. Por eso te recomiendo en cada clase crear un constructor e iniciar las propiedades ahi como te puse en mi primer ejemplo.

Comment: Si me sirvió demacrado, de igual forma te doy un +1 por como dices que estaba repetida, ahora echare un vistazo al link que me dejaste. Muchas gracias (: